# Acsses to speakers properties in Win7

Tags: c++, windows-7

I want to mute microphone in Speakers propeties.

My application is written in c++.

I know how to adjust/mute speakers levels using IMMDevice *device

```
IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
hr = device->Activate( __uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&endpointVolume) );
float volume=0.3;
hr=endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(volume,NULL);
hr= endpointVolume->SetMute(TRUE, NULL);
```

How can I mute microphone?